# Can Hreflang Tag Used for a Single Language Site?

Tags: google-search-console

When I check my site on google, I see a warn about hreflang tag. It says "Your site has no hreflang tags". I read documents but I confused. All examples about alternate languages for the websites. I wonder that Should I use hreflang tag for my single language page?

[Google document is here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6059209)

Comment: If you have no alternate language versions, then you cannot use alternate language tag.  Google mainly uses the hreflang to be able to show the correct version for the correct audiences. I wouldn't worry about that warning, it should not affect ranking. The warning is just a generic warning.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen So, can I ignoring the warning?

Comment: I would ignore it, yes.

Comment: Thank you @AllanS.Hansen